# Display line when using Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible when in one line, there are two or more characters matched with pattern, we only print the line one time?

For example:

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(("V+N+PN+")).matcher(line);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

output:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,34 lastmatch=VVNNNNNNNNNPNNNN]
NVNVVNNNNNNVVNNNNNNNNNPNNNNPNNONNN
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,42 lastmatch=VVNPNNN]
OSNVVNPNNNVNVNNVVNNPNNNNNNNNPVNNNPNNNPNNNO
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,42 lastmatch=VVNNPNNNNNNNN]
OSNVVNPNNNVNVNNVVNNPNNNNNNNNPVNNNPNNNPNNNO
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,42 lastmatch=VNNNPNNN]
OSNVVNPNNNVNVNNVVNNPNNNNNNNNPVNNNPNNNPNNNO
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,5 lastmatch=VNPN]
NVNPN
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,38 lastmatch=VNNPNNN]
NNNNVPNNNNVNNPNNNVVPNNPNNVVPNVVNVVPNNO
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,36 lastmatch=VNPNN]
SNVNPNNVNNNONVNNVVVPNNVVVVPNNPNNNNNN
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=V+N+PN+ region=0,9 lastmatch=VVVNPN]
NNVVVNPNO
```

Actually, what I want is the output will display the line one time only even though there are more than one matched with pattern per line.

Comment: Unclear. What line do you want printed once? Can you provide the output you want?

Comment: First of all, you probably don't want a `while` loop then. Second of all, read the docs.

Comment: what I mean is, let say if one input has more than one that matched with pattern, so it is possible to display the input in one time only instead if display it when it is matched?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print matched lines only once, just use `if` instead of `while`:

```
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(line);
```

A `Matcher` does not *need* to walk the whole input.